# How do I aggregate data at a higher level without a separate select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that I want to aggregate at a specific level, but also at a broader/higher level. Example, let's say I have Sales data for stores across the country and I want to look at aggregated data by state, and regions (a few states combined) as well.

So data granularity is something like: `Year|Store|State|Sales`. Some `State`  fields are prefixed by a region tag to allow for grouping by that region. So in the Pacific northwest, Washington, Oregon, and Montana are prefixed with `PNW-`.

This query gets me mostly what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT
Store, State, Year, avg(Sales)
FROM sales
GROUP BY Store, State, Year
```

But let's say I also want to group the a region of states together, as another grouping. I want to still have data for all the states in that grouping as separate rows, and also the region grouping.

Is there a way to do this without having to do some other select statement and join back to the query above?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Look into window functions (`OVER` clause).

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [`GROUPING SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-grouping-sets--)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be better than the narrative/

Comment: Without some details this just isn't possible to answer.

Comment: You need a way to define the regions.  I am unclear if you are asking about how to define the regions or how to aggregate at that level.

Answer (score 0):

[Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484879/larnu) is right, you should use grouping sets

```
with

sales_with_region as (
    select
        Store,
        left(State, 4) as Region, -- use only if it is always first 4 symbols
        State,
        Year,
        Sales
    from
        sales
)

select
    Store,
    Region,
    coalesce(State, 'TOTAL') as State,
    Year,
    avg(Sales) as avg_sales
from
    sales_with_region
group by
    grouping sets (
        (Store, Region, State, Year),
        (Store, Region, Year)
    )
```